What is a better formula to provide the text after a specific character or wording?
I am using an older version of Excel so i cant use a lot of the new formulas that would make my life easier.
I am currenly trying to get all the text after a specific character to appear.
example '12345678 CustomerName
Desired Results is for the "CustomerName"
The starting numbers can change in length.
I already tried a function called Textafter() but it doesnt work.
we are using 2019 version, and the textafter function doesnt populate as an option in the lists avaiable. i get the #Name? error
If this the best formula or is there something better i can use?
=IFERROR(MID(K2,LEN(K2),SEARCH(" ",K2,LEN(K2))),MID(K2,9,30))
i have been doing some addittional research and came across this source https://community.smartsheet.com/discussion/97017/how-can-i-find-a-position-of-a-character-in-a-string   but it still looks more extensive than i think this should be.

What's the error you're getting on TEXTAFTER()? And exactly which version do you have? An older might as well be 2019 or 2021...

we are using 2019 version, and teh textafter function doesnt populate as an option in the lists avaiable.  Thouhg i hav been using some research and found this  other website but i havent tested it out yet.
https://community.smartsheet.com/discussion/97017/how-can-i-find-a-position-of-a-character-in-a-string
i get the #Name? error

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309041/excel-year-week-combination-calculation

If you are looking for text after a space, and if there is no space, text from the 9th character, then here's how you can do it:
=IFERROR(MID(K2,FIND(" ",K2)+1,LEN(K2)),MID(K2,9,LEN(K2)))

Or a bit shorter version:
=MID(K2,IFERROR(FIND(" ",K2)+1,9),LEN(K2))


Another way could be:
=REPLACE(K2,1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",K2),8),)
Instead of starting from the found space character it removes characters up to there. If not found it removes the first 8 characters.

To find the letter string that starts after the last digit in the string, you can use:
=TRIM(MID(A1,1+MAX(IFERROR(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1),0)),255))

This

FIND the position of the last digit in the string
add one (1) to get the first non-digit
Use MID to return the non-digit portion of the string
TRIM to remove any leading/trailing spaces

